# Secure Spring Boot API without user authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm currently developing a few services with spring boot and some security concerns came in mind. All the exposed endpoints are public and do not require any user/password authentication. However, these services cannot be easily accessible by a caller other than our front-end application, since we must gather some user information through a form, in which a captcha performs a validation. Because of that, we need to ensure that the services are only invoked by this front-end application and that fake requests are denied.

Due to these requirements, i initially thought that making the endpoints accessible via https was enough. Notwithstanding, the possibility of replay attacks and spoofing still concerns me.

So, reading a few articles i came up with the following draft:

Please refer the client as the front-end application.

1. client and server should share a key-pair (public and private keys).
2. For every request, the following must be satisfied:

- client creates a unique nonce (random number)
- client generates a HMAC-SHA1 token with the shared private key

  ```
   token = hmac('sha1', private_key, public_key + timestamp + nonce);
  ```
- client must send the public_key, timestamp, nonce and token in header

3. upon receiving a request, the server checks if all the header params are present and then calculates the same hmac-sha1 token and compares with the received value from the client.
4. the nonce is then added to a cache manager, so that duplicated requisitions are discarded.
5. if any of header parameters are missing or if the calculated token is different from the one sent by the client, the requesition is also discarded.

Is this an appropriate approach? Are the benefits of such overhead worth?

These are the codes i currently have:

```
@Service

public class APIAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

@Value("${security.http.api_key}")
private String apiKeyValue;

@Value("${security.http.api_key_header}")
private String apiKeyRequestHeader;

@Value("${security.valid_timestamp.thresold}")
private String timestampThresold;

@Value("${security.valid_timestamp.header}")
private String timestampHeader;

@Value("${security.nonce.header}")
private String nonce;

@Value("${security.token.header}")
private String tokenHeader;

@Value("${security.private_key}")
private String privateKey;

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) authentication.getPrincipal();

    if (!apiKeyValue.equals(request.getParameter(apiKeyRequestHeader))) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("The API key was not found or not the expected value.");
    }

    String timestamp = request.getParameter(timestampHeader);
    if(timestamp == null) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Timestamp was not found or its value is invalid.");
    }

    Date requestIssueDate = Util.parseDate(timestamp, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
    if(requestIssueDate == null) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Timestamp was not found or its value is invalid.");
    }

    long expired = System.currentTimeMillis() - Integer.valueOf( timestampThresold );
    if (requestIssueDate.getTime() > expired) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Timestamp was not found or its value is invalid.");
    }

    // HMAC('SHA1', 'API_KEY', 'TOKEN GENERATED IN CLIENT');
    // TOKEN GENERATED IN CLIENT = HMAC('SHA1', 'API_KEY', 'SECRET_KEY + TIMESTAMP + NONCE');
    String tokenFromClient = request.getParameter(tokenHeader);     
    String calculatedToken = HMACSignatureUtil.calculateHMAC(privateKey, apiKeyValue + timestamp + nonce); 

    if(!tokenFromClient.equals(calculatedToken)) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid token.");
    }

    authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
    return authentication;
}
```

This is the ConfigurerAdapter

```
@Autowired
private APIAuthenticationManager apiAuthenticationManager;
    
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    APIKeyAuthFilter filter = new APIKeyAuthFilter();
    filter.setAuthenticationManager( apiAuthenticationManager );

    http.csrf().disable()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and().addFilter(filter).authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    
    http.requiresChannel()
    .anyRequest(). requiresSecure();
}
```